# Debugging Salesforce IoT

Tags: debug-logs, iot

I'm playing with the new Salesforce IoT. 
I did some trailhead module to test this new function and then I activated the debug to see how it was, but when I looked in the debug logs I didn't see anything.
Do you know if it is possible to debug various transition passage from a state to another?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce IoT processes platform events, which are ephemeral, so it's a bit tricky for debugging.

The easiest way while building is to create a tracker for the partition key used by your test device:

[image]

This will probably give you everything you need to trace rule execution, variable values, and state transitions.